# How to get git log -p as json

Tags: json, git, git-log

I want to run `git log -p` and get the results as JSON.
I couldn't find a way to do it from the [pretty format documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats), but I am probably missing something.

The desired result I have in mind will be something like:

```
[{
  "commit": SHA,
  "author": AUTHOR,
  "date": DATE,
  "commit_message": COMMIT_MSG,
  "full_diff": FULL_DIFF
}]
```

Comment: @phd I saw those questions and their answers before I asked, and the documentation is pretty clear about getting git log as json in general, but I can't find a way to add the diff (-p) part to the json structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to implement with `git log` because there is no format for diff. It's possible to script using plumbing commands:

```
echo '['
git rev-list HEAD | while read sha1; do
    full_diff="$(git show --format='' $sha1 | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g')"
    git --no-pager show --format="{%n  \"commit\": \"%H\",%n  \"author\": \"%an\",%n  \"date\": \"%ad\",%n  \"commit_message\": \"%s\",%n  \"full_diff\": \"$full_diff\"%n}," -s $sha1
    done
echo ']'
```

A few notes:

```
git rev-list HEAD | while read sha1; do…done
```

Means "run through all commits, read every hash into variable `sha1`".

```
full_diff="$(…)"
```

Extract the full diff for the commit. Replace `"` with `\"` to avoid generating broken JSON.

```
git show --format="…" -s $sha1
```

Print information about the commit in the given format. Add the full diff separately.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I just had to make a minor change to your 3rd line and replace newlines with literal \n so it will be a valid JSON.
`full_diff="$(git show --format='' $sha1 | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' | awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}')"`