# Git Log Multiline Output

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I'm trying to get git log to output the **full commit message** in a **multi-line** format or with placeholder characters so that I can replace them later.

I would like the output including the id, author, date and multi-line message of the commit to be in a xml or json format.

I am using batch, since i want to run the snippet on VisualStudio prebuild.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66607984/7976758 (JSON)?

Comment: @phd No unfortually not. The Output of my Custom Format (git show -10 --pretty=format:"%h|%an|%aI|%s" -s) is still missing the linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show -10 --pretty=format:"%h|%an|%aI|%B" -s
```